# get regex pattern for current URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, checkbox

I have a url like this:
http://mysite.aspx/results.aspx?s=bcs_locations&k="Hospital" OR "Office" OR...
The terms after k= are coming from checkboxes, when checked the checkboxes values are being passed. Now I need to get the current URL and get all the values after k, so if there are two 'Hospital' and Office then grab those values and make the checkboxes with those values checked.. Trying hard to persist the checked checkboxes coz on refresh, all the checked checkboxes loose their state..

```
Hospitals<input name="LocType" type="checkbox" value="Hospital"/> &#160; 
Offices<input name="LocType" type="checkbox"  value="Office"/> &#160; 
Emergency Centers<input name="LocType" type="checkbox"  value="Emergency"/>
```

What I have so far is: 
I want the regular expression for such URl pattern..can someone help?

```
 var value = window.location.href.match(/[?&]k=([^&#]+)/) || [];
    if (value.length == 2) {
        $('input[name="LocType"][value="' + value[1] + '"]').prop("checked", true);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what we use to grab info from the query string. It's from another S.O. answer that I can't find.  But this will give you an object which represents all the options in the query string.

```
var qs = function(){
    var query_string = {};
    if(window.location.search){
        (function () {
            var e,
                a = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
                r = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
                d = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(a, " ")); },
                q = window.location.search.substring(1);

            while (e = r.exec(q)){
               query_string[d(e[1])] = d(e[2]);
            }
        }());
    }
    return query_string;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
var MyApp = {
    urlArgs:{}
};

MyApp.processUrlArgs = function() {
    this.urlArgs = {};
    var str = window.location.search ? window.location.search.substring(1) : false;
    if( ! str ) return;
    var sp = str.split(/&+/);
    var rx = /^([^=]+)(=(.+))?/;
    var k, v, i, m;
    for( i in sp ) {
        m = rx.exec( sp[i] );
    if( ! m ) continue;
    this.urlArgs[decodeURIComponent(m[1])] = decodeURIComponent(m[3]);
    }
};
```

But what I don't understand is why do it like this? If you work in asp why don't you use [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx#Mtps_DropDownFilterText)?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function getParamsFromUrl(url){
    var paramsStr = url.split('?')[1],
        params = paramsStr.split('&'),
        paramsObj = {};

    for(var i=0;i < params.length; i++){
        var param= params[i].split('='),
            name = param[0],
            value = param[1];
        paramsObj[name] = value;
    }
    return paramsObj;
}

var testUrl = 'http://mysite.aspx/results.aspx?s=bcs_locations&k=Hospital';
getParamsFromUrl(testUrl);//return: Object { s="bcs_locations", k="Hospital"}
```